Value of sheaf on an open point?
$\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
Let $X$ be a scheme, and $x\in X$ be an open point, that $\{x\}$ is open, I want to determine what $\O_X(x)$ is (up to isomorphism). We have that $x$ is contained in an affine open set, $U=\Spec A$, so we can identify $x$ with a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $A$. It follows that $\O_X(x)\cong \O_{\Spec A}(\mathfrak p)$.
Now the sheaf of rings on $\Spec A$ is induced by the sheaf on a basis of basic opens given by $\O_{\Spec A}(U_g)=A_g$. On any regular open set $U$, we have that:
$$\O_{\Spec A}(U)=\left\{(s_\mathfrak p)\in \prod_{\mathfrak p\in U}A_{\mathfrak p}:\forall \mathfrak q\in U, \exists U_g\subset U,\mathfrak q\in U_g, \text{ and } f/g^k\in A_g,\text{ with } s_{\mathfrak p}=(f/g^k)_\mathfrak p \forall \mathfrak p\in U_g\right\}$$
Now if $U=\{\mathfrak p\}$ I strongly suspect that $A_\mathfrak p$, as if $a/b\in A_{\mathfrak p}$, then $a/b\in A_b$, and $U_b$ contains $\mathfrak p$. The stalk of $a/b\in A_b$ is then just $a/b$ viewed as an element of $A_{\mathfrak p}$. However, this is not quite the condition that the sheaf on a base sets out. Indeed, we would need that $U_b=\{\mathfrak p\}$.
I guess if $\{\mathfrak p\}$ is open, then it can be written as the union of basic opens $U_g$, but since $\{\mathfrak p\}$ is singleton, then we must have that there exists a $g$ such that $U_g=\{\mathfrak p\}$. This implies that $g\in \mathfrak q$ for every other prime ideal $\mathfrak q$, and so $\O_{\Spec A}(\mathfrak p)$ is isomorphic to $A_g$, as well as elements of $A_{\mathfrak p}$ which are in the image of the natural map $A_g\rightarrow A_{\mathfrak p}$. Is there any reason this map should be an isomorphism? If not in generality, can we impose such a condition when $\Spec A$ is a finite union of maximal ideals?

I'm unsure I understand your question. You showed that $A_g \xrightarrow{\sim} A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is an isomorphism when ${\mathfrak{p}}$ is open. Are you looking for more general conditions for when this holds ?

@FrançoisGatine I did not show that it was an isomorphism. For example, suppose $a/g^k=0\in A_\mathfrak p$ then there is an $s\notin \mathfrak p$ such that $sa=0$. How can we conclude from this that $g^ma=0$ as well?

You showed that ${\mathfrak{p}} = U_g$ for some $g$, so $\mathcal{O}({\mathfrak{p}}) = \mathcal{O}(U_g) = A_g$ as you noted. Observe that $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the colimit of the $\mathcal{O}(U)$ for all $U$ open neighborhoods of $x=\mathfrak{p}$, but every single one of these $U$ contains $U_g$, and $U_g$ is also one of those $U$, hence $A_{\mathfrak{p}} = \varinjlim_U \mathcal{O}(U) = \mathcal{O}(U_g) = A_g$. Because the colimit system is built with restriction maps, you do find that the natural morphism $A_g \rightarrow A_p$ is an isomorphism.

@FrançoisGatine I see. Is there a way to conclude this more concretely?

I'm struggling to find a purely ring-theoretic proof. From your comment above, notice that if $s$ is invertible, we are done, because then $a=0$ in $A$, hence also in its localization $A_g$. If $s$ isn't invertible, make it invertible by considering $A_s$. This works precisely because $A_g = (A_s)_{g/1}$, where $g/1 \in A_s$ (this is valid for any $s \notin \mathfrak{p}$ because $U_g = {\mathfrak{p}}$). Now we know that $\frac{a}{1}=0$ in $A_s$, hence also in its localization $A_g$. The argument is clearer by drawing the situation, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is the only element on the island $U_g$

@FrançoisGatine I think I see, for all $s\notin \mathfrak p$, we have that $A_g=A_{sg}$. Using this I think I can also prove subjectivity. The stalk argument is definitely cleaner though

Since $X$ is a scheme and $\{x\}$ is an open subset containing $x$, by the very definition of a scheme, there is an open affine subscheme $x \in U \subseteq \{x\}$. So, necessarily we have that $\{x\}$ is already an affine scheme. The corresponding commutative ring $A$ has exactly one prime ideal, which means that it is a $0$-dimensional local ring. The structure sheaf evaluated $\{x\}$ is just that ring $A$.

Sure but this tells us nothing about what that ring is in relation to any open affines containing it.

It does when you go through the proof that $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is a scheme. The calculations in your post and the comments are just not necessary to answer the question you asked. Maybe you want to ask something else in the end - but then please specify it precisely.

How so? Is this somehow different from the process outlined in the comments
